# Controlled checkbox in React

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I'm trying to put all checked checkboxes in the state array. I am able to add values to the array, but I cannot delete the value when I uncheck the box. I've tried using splice and delete by index, also tried deleting through a filter. It works, but it works slowly and incorrectly. For example I can uncheck all the checkboxes and one value stay in the state. Please check what I'm doing wrong
Here is a Sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-mccarthy-37ue3?file=/src/scenes/App.js) and my code below

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    address: [],
  })

  const checkboxChange = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target
    if (checked === true) {
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        address: [...prevState.address, name],
      }))
    }
    if (checked === false) {
      setState((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        address: [...prevState.address].filter((it) => it.id !== it.id),
      }))
    }
  }
```

```
{list.map((it, index) => (
        <div key={it.id}>
          <label>
            <input
              className="mr-2"
              checked={state.address.index}
              key={it.id}
              name={it.id}
              defaultValue="false"
              onChange={checkboxChange}
              type="checkbox"
            />
            {it.name}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
```

Comment: You have uncontrolled inputs and `it.id !== it.id` will *always* evaluate false`. Why are you storing checked state in an array?

Comment: It looks like you got your answer, but FYI you should never use `splice` on a react state because it mutates the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

You are comparing `it.id !== it.id` which will *always* evaluate to false.

## Solution

`state.address` is an array of the ids, not objects with an `id` property, and you want to compare each one against the input's `name` in the `onChange` event object.

1. Just filter `prevState.address`
2. Compare `el !== name`

Code

```
const checkboxChange = (e) => {
  const { name, checked } = e.target;

  if (checked) {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      address: [...prevState.address, name],
    }))
  } else {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      address: prevState.address.filter((el) => el !== name),
    }))
  }
}
```

[image: Edit controlled-checkbox-in-react]

## Controlled Inputs

If you really want your inputs to be controlled then I suggest:

1. Store the checked values in a map
2. Simply toggle the checked values from `onChange` event
3. Use the `value` attribute versus the `defaultValue` attribute of the input

Code

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    address: {}, // <-- object map
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state)
  }, [state])

  const checkboxChange = (e) => {
    const { name } = e.target
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      address: {
        ...prevState.address,
        [name]: !prevState.address[name], // <-- toggle state
      },
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((it, index) => (
        <div key={it.id}>
          <label>
            <input
              className="mr-2"
              checked={state.address.index}
              key={it.id}
              name={it.id}
              value={state.address[it.id]} // <-- set from checked state
              onChange={checkboxChange}
              type="checkbox"
            />
            {it.name}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: Edit controlled-checkbox-in-react (forked)]

Comment: ```[name]: !prevState.address[name]?``` is a boolean value, so it wouldn't have the `checked` property

Comment: @ZacharyHaber Thanks for catching my copy/paste bug, though it still *technically* worked, it should have been `value={state.address[it.id].checked}` :p. Updated both snippet and sandbox.